# Save a UIImage on Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, binary-data

How do I save a photo picked by a `UIImagePickerController` in core data. In my data model I have it set up as Type `Binary Data` and allows it to store Externally.
Here is my code so far.

```
- (IBAction)addPhoto:(id)sender {
_picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
_picker.delegate = self;
_picker.allowsEditing = NO;
_picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:_picker animated:YES completion:nil];


}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];


[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.imageView reloadInputViews];



}
```

Comment: What is the size of your image (in bytes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `UIImage` conforms to `NSCoding`, all you need to do is change the attribute type from "binary" to "transformable". Then you can assign a `UIImage` to the attribute directly, and Core Data will automatically invoke `NSCoding` methods on it to convert to and from binary data.

In your code, you would just add this:

```
[object setValue:image forKey:@"name of your image attribute here"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // One option:
    NSData *imageData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7);
    // Second option.
   // NSData *imagenData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

object.theNameOfYourBinaryDataAttribute = imageData;

[context save:nil]; // Or handling error.

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.imageView reloadInputViews];



}
```